# MySensors GatewaySerial code not compiling

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, eeprom, compilation-errors

I am trying to compile GatewaySerial code from MySensors library for my Arduino Leonardo and it gives me EEPROM errors.

Gateway code:

```
/**
* The MySensors Arduino library handles the wireless radio link and protocol
* between your home built sensors/actuators and HA controller of choice.
* The sensors forms a self healing radio network with optional repeaters. Each
* repeater and gateway builds a routing tables in EEPROM which keeps track of the
* network topology allowing messages to be routed to nodes.
*
* Created by Henrik Ekblad 
* Copyright (C) 2013-2015 Sensnology AB
* Full contributor list: https://github.com/mysensors/Arduino/graphs/contributors
*
* Documentation: http://www.mysensors.org
* Support Forum: http://forum.mysensors.org
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* version 2 as published by the Free Software Foundation.
*
*******************************
*
* DESCRIPTION
* The ArduinoGateway prints data received from sensors on the serial link.
* The gateway accepts input on seral which will be sent out on radio network.
*
* The GW code is designed for Arduino Nano 328p / 16MHz
*
* Wire connections (OPTIONAL):
* - Inclusion button should be connected between digital pin 3 and GND
* - RX/TX/ERR leds need to be connected between +5V (anode) and digital pin 6/5/4 with resistor 270-330R in a series
*
* LEDs (OPTIONAL):
* - To use the feature, uncomment any of the MY_DEFAULT_xx_LED_PINs
* - RX (green) - blink fast on radio message recieved. In inclusion mode will blink fast only on presentation recieved
* - TX (yellow) - blink fast on radio message transmitted. In inclusion mode will blink slowly
* - ERR (red) - fast blink on error during transmission error or recieve crc error
*
*/

// Enable debug prints to serial monitor
#define MY_DEBUG


// Enable and select radio type attached
#define MY_RADIO_NRF24
//#define MY_RADIO_NRF5_ESB
//#define MY_RADIO_RFM69
//#define MY_RADIO_RFM95

// Set LOW transmit power level as default, if you have an amplified NRF-module and
// power your radio separately with a good regulator you can turn up PA level.
#define MY_RF24_PA_LEVEL RF24_PA_LOW

// Enable serial gateway
#define MY_GATEWAY_SERIAL

// Define a lower baud rate for Arduino's running on 8 MHz (Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V & SenseBender)
#if F_CPU == 8000000L
#define MY_BAUD_RATE 38400
#endif

// Enable inclusion mode
#define MY_INCLUSION_MODE_FEATURE
// Enable Inclusion mode button on gateway
//#define MY_INCLUSION_BUTTON_FEATURE

// Inverses behavior of inclusion button (if using external pullup)
//#define MY_INCLUSION_BUTTON_EXTERNAL_PULLUP

// Set inclusion mode duration (in seconds)
#define MY_INCLUSION_MODE_DURATION 60
// Digital pin used for inclusion mode button
//#define MY_INCLUSION_MODE_BUTTON_PIN  3

// Set blinking period
#define MY_DEFAULT_LED_BLINK_PERIOD 300

// Inverses the behavior of leds
//#define MY_WITH_LEDS_BLINKING_INVERSE

// Flash leds on rx/tx/err
// Uncomment to override default HW configurations
//#define MY_DEFAULT_ERR_LED_PIN 4  // Error led pin
//#define MY_DEFAULT_RX_LED_PIN  6  // Receive led pin
//#define MY_DEFAULT_TX_LED_PIN  5  // the PCB, on board LED

#include 

void setup()
{
    // Setup locally attached sensors
}

void presentation()
{
    // Present locally attached sensors
}

void loop()
{
    // Send locally attached sensor data here
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from /home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.cpp:20:0,
                 from /home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/MySensors.h:64,
                 from /home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/examples/GatewaySerial/GatewaySerial.ino:86:
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MyTransport.cpp: In function 'bool transportAssignNodeID(uint8_t)':
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.h:54:82: error: 'eeprom_update_byte' was not declared in this scope
 #define hwWriteConfig(__pos, __val) eeprom_update_byte((uint8_t*)(__pos), (__val))
                                                                                  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MyTransport.cpp:503:3: note: in expansion of macro 'hwWriteConfig'
   hwWriteConfig(EEPROM_NODE_ID_ADDRESS, newNodeId);
   ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MyTransport.cpp: In function 'void transportSetRoute(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.h:54:82: error: 'eeprom_update_byte' was not declared in this scope
 #define hwWriteConfig(__pos, __val) eeprom_update_byte((uint8_t*)(__pos), (__val))
                                                                                  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MyTransport.cpp:1065:2: note: in expansion of macro 'hwWriteConfig'
  hwWriteConfig(EEPROM_ROUTES_ADDRESS + node, route);
  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp: In function 'void _begin()':
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.h:54:82: error: 'eeprom_update_byte' was not declared in this scope
 #define hwWriteConfig(__pos, __val) eeprom_update_byte((uint8_t*)(__pos), (__val))
                                                                                  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp:140:2: note: in expansion of macro 'hwWriteConfig'
  hwWriteConfig(EEPROM_PARENT_NODE_ID_ADDRESS, MY_PARENT_NODE_ID);
  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp: In function 'bool _processInternalMessages()':
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.h:56:114: error: 'eeprom_update_block' was not declared in this scope
 #define hwWriteConfigBlock(__buf, __pos, __length) eeprom_update_block((void*)(__buf), (void*)(__pos), (__length))
                                                                                                                  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp:415:4: note: in expansion of macro 'hwWriteConfigBlock'
    hwWriteConfigBlock((void*)&_coreConfig.controllerConfig, (void*)EEPROM_CONTROLLER_CONFIG_ADDRESS,
    ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp: In function 'void saveState(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/hal/architecture/AVR/MyHwAVR.h:54:82: error: 'eeprom_update_byte' was not declared in this scope
 #define hwWriteConfig(__pos, __val) eeprom_update_byte((uint8_t*)(__pos), (__val))
                                                                                  ^
/home/szymex/Arduino/libraries/MySensors/core/MySensorsCore.cpp:499:2: note: in expansion of macro 'hwWriteConfig'
  hwWriteConfig(EEPROM_LOCAL_CONFIG_ADDRESS+pos, value);
  ^
exit status 1
```

Comment: What Arduino IDE version are you using? What platform (Windows, Linux, Mac)? Using IDE 1.8.1 on Windows, I added the MySensors library, opened the Gateway Serial example, set the device to Arduino Leonardo, and it compiled just fine.

Comment: I am missing something? There is practically no code and `#include` is missing the filename.

Comment: @gre_gor this appears to be just the example code from the MySensors library, unchanged.

Comment: The sketch and library are here: https://github.com/mysensors/MySensors. The sketch in that repository does have the full `#include` statement and it compiles for Leonardo fine for me to with Arduino IDE 1.8.5.

Comment: Also asked at: https://github.com/mysensors/MySensors/issues/1007 and https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/8045/problem-with-compiling-gatewayserial. If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Comment: It's arduino ide 1.8.4 on linux mint 18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed here:
https://github.com/mysensors/MySensors/issues/1007
I needed to update Arduino IDE, reinstall board definitions and MySensors library